# Simulating Bottlenecks using H2/Hibernate/C3P0

Tags: hibernate, h2, c3p0

I want to run some local performance tests where I would like to simulate a database bottleneck.

I am using Hibernate with C3P0 and hitting an H2 database (Server Mode).

What I would like to do is find a way to artificially slow down the database queries in some manner.

I have tried limiting the size of my C3P0 connection pools, but it seems that despite that everything is able to keep up just fine.

Is there some property I can adjust either on H2 or maybe C3P0 that would allow me to essentially slow down the database queries?

Comment: Add millions of records and do queries that don't use an index

Comment: Unfortunately that is a bit outside the scope of the test that I am trying to do. I am trying to avoid having to create/modify queries.

Comment: And why do you want to make that test?

Comment: The details of why are difficult. But the gist of it is that I have multiple different architectures that I want to test to show how each might perform when faced with a database bottleneck. In order to do that I need to simulate a bottleneck.

Comment: You could add a proxy between your app and the database https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Cool idea. But I was hoping to do it with the technologies already in use. I was hoping there might just be a setting somewhere I could use to "de-optimize" the database.

Comment: No. That wouldn't make sense 